# How to know whether xgboost is running in parallel?

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

I'm training a `xgboost` regressor on a Linux server with 28 cores.

I installed `xgboost` by running

```
mkdir build 
cd build 
cmake ..
make -j28
```

The `xgboost` regressor is constructed with

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor as r
model = r(max_depth = 6,
          n_estimators = 100, 
          n_jobs = 28)
```

While the script is running, I observe with `top` command that

```
PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND 
20   0 13.970g 0.011t  25700 R  2800  9.3  93:07.84 python
```

Does it mean `xgboost` is utilizing all the 28 cores for training the model?

Since hyper-threading is enabled, can I build `xgboost` with `make -j56` and then set `n_jobs = 56` in `xgboost` model?

Comment: If i rememebr correctly, the `-jN` argument of `make` executes compilation in `N` threads. That does not affect the number of available threads in the library execution. So you can use any value you want. But beware, that hyperthreading might be not fully performant, i.e. processing time with `n_jobs` double the cores will not be halved. You will need to test it yourself.